# Conditionally use switchmap or exhaustmap angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Sorry if this question has been answered but I've searched and couldn't find it myself.

What I want to do is call a function that returns data from 1 of 2 places. Either gets cached data or gets new data from API. I am using angular 7 and have been trying to implement an observable that conditionally uses switchMap and exhaustMap. I have a decent understanding of Observables, but I know there's still something I don't understand. I was thinking of using exhaustMap as the default method which pulls from cache. But if I need to get the newest data from the API, I want to use switchMap to ignore retrieving from cache and get fresh data.

I found a stackblitz playground and forked it to do some testing. Here's my attempt https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-conditional-data

And this is the relevant code.

```
this.observable.pipe(
      map((val: string) => {
        if (/^true/.test(val)) {
          this.mergeVal = 'switch ' + val;
          return switchMap(val => {
            // console.log("SwitchMap val: ", val);
            this.switchVal = val;
            return of(val);
          })
        } else {
          this.mergeVal = 'exhaust ' + val;
          return exhaustMap(val => {
            // console.log("resolve val: ", val);
            return new Promise(resolve => {
              setTimeout(() => {
                this.exhaustVal = val;
                resolve(val);
              }, 3000);
            });
          })
        }
      })
    ).subscribe(
      data => {
      //  this.observable; 
      this.subscribeVal = 'data: ' + data;
      },
      err => {
        this.subscribeVal = 'error';
      },
      () => {
        this.subscribeVal = 'complete';
      }
    );
  }
```

**UPDATE 2020-06-02**
I added a service that makes an api call to better align with my current setup that this is going to be applied to. moved away exhaustMap and switchMap with hopes of solving the same problem using the help from people who have posted here

Now I think the problem I have is in this part of the code but I'm not sure how to fix it

```
  dummyAPI = 'https://swapi.dev/api/';

  cacheSubject: Subject<any> = new Subject();
  cacheObservable: Observable<any> = this.cacheSubject.asObservable().pipe(
    startWith(this.http.get(this.dummyAPI).pipe(
      map(val => {
        console.log('startWith: ', val);
        return this.now('dataService', true);
      })
    )),
    concatMap(val => val),
    shareReplay({refCount: true})
  );

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  now(fromId, val = false) {
    return `${val} ${moment().format('hh:mm:ss')} COMP ${fromId}`;
  }

  updateDataFromAPI(fromId, getFromAPI) {
    const val = this.now(fromId, getFromAPI);
    if (getFromAPI) {
      this.cacheSubject.next(
        this.http.get(this.dummyAPI).pipe(
          tap(val => {
            console.log("tap dummyAPI before delay: ", val);
          }),
          delay(5000),
          tap(val => {
            console.log("tap dummyAPI after delay: ", val);
          }),
        )
      );
    } else {
      this.cacheSubject.next(of(val));
    }
  }

  getData(fromId, getFromAPI?) {
    if (getFromAPI) {
      this.updateDataFromAPI(fromId, getFromAPI);
    }
    return this.cacheObservable.pipe(take(1));
  }
```

The problem I'm having is that the cacheObservable subscription (from getData) isn't waiting for the cacheSubject value (from calling next through updateDataFromAPI) to respond with the api data before cacheObservable completes.

Comment: when I needed to do something similar I had a cache variable that hold cached data inside service and gets populated by tapping into observable. Then based on boolean flag either return of(this.cachedData) or http.get(..). if you want to share data between subscribers then you'd use .shareReplay()

Comment: @ihorbond Thank you! I think I might be going that route seeing as how I've spent so much time trying to figure this out without success. I still want to see this through, though because I want anything that is subscribed to the observable to wait for the data from the api if it tried retrieving the data after the call to the api but before we get the response back from api. Let me know if that's unclear and I'll try to explain better

Comment: I'm not sure why do you need to decide between these 2. If their usage would be decided at _subscription time_, then I'd go for `defer()`. But in your case, you need to make that decision when the value arrives, which makes me think that there's no way to properly use `switchMap` and/or `exhaustMap`. What would happen if another outer value would arrive while an `exhaustMap` will be active ?

Comment: @AndreiGătej Good point. I'm going to look into shareReplay and see if that gives me what I want. I was trying to use switchMap and exhaustMap because of the purpose they serve (as in switchMap will ignore the response of any unfinished calls if a new call is made and exhaustMap will ignore any new calls until the initial call receives a response) I now believe the method I was attempting was incorrect and impossible and will be looking into shareReplay

Answer (score 1):

This won't work. Because you want to change the stream based on the emit of `this.observable`.

The idea of `exhaustMap` is to skip all emits of `this.observable` until the child stream of `exhaustMap` has been finished.

In your case I would suggest to use `shareReplay(1)` that would keep serving cache until an emit comes from `this.observable`.

```js
const cachedStream$ = this.observable.pipe(
  startWith(null), // to trigger the first load.
  switchMap(() => this.http.get('http://my-data.url')),
  shareReplay(1),
);

cachedStream$.subscribe(cached => this.cached1 = cached);
cachedStream$.subscribe(cached => this.cached2 = cached);
cachedStream$.subscribe(cached => this.cached3 = cached);

this.observable.next(); // refresh the value from the backend.
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try implementing this and report back. I am going to see if exhaustMap will work in place of switchMap

Comment: From my understanding, shareReplay(1) will send the last "emitted" value. For example: if data has been retrieved already, the next subscription receives that data. Even if .next() was triggered before the new subscription with an api call that hasn't responded yet. So $obs1 has initial data. $obs1 calls for new data from api. Before the api responds, a new subscription is made and its first value is from the initial data rather than waiting for the current observable (api call) that is still processing. Is that correct?

Comment: About shareReplay, you are right, it always returns current value on subscription and notifies everybody about a new value if it came from the parent. If you want to avoid this behavior and to notify only you can use `share()`. It doesn't return current value only updates when they happen.